# MessageBox in Python with Help button?

Tags: python, windows

(This may be more of a Windows question than a Python question, but either way, I'd appreciate some help.)  I want my Python program to display a MessageBox with a Help button that, when clicked, forwards a URL to the user's default browser - but I'm finding that either Python doesn't implement the full MessageBox interface, or else I'm not understanding how to use it.  I suspect it's a little of both, because I had to define the MB_HELP constant myself, yet once I did so, the Help button did appear in the dialog.

```
    user_response = messageBox(       \
        dialog_text,                  \
        dialog_title,                 \
        MESSAGEBOXFLAGS.OKCANCEL |    \
        MESSAGEBOXFLAGS.ICONWARNING | \
        MB_HELP                       \
    )
```

My question is, how can I (in the context of Python) connect the button to the URL that I want it to forward to the browser?  I'm not sure if I can just pass the URL somehow in the statement that creates the MessageBox, or if I have to create a function to do that and connect that to the Help button.

Comment: I believe the ID of the Help button gets returned by the function.

Comment: I strongly suspect your reply is inaccurate, but even if correct, it's still useless to me, because clicking the Help button doesn't terminate the MessageBox function the way OK or Cancel would.